# Delete DB entry on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Lets imagine we have this kind of code:

```
//...
$item = $xyz->findOneBy(array('type'=>'abc'));
$em->remove($item);
$second = $xyz->findOneBy(array('type'=>'abc'));
//...
```

Does this $second get any values from DB ? My goal is to get $second as an empty list. But i'm not sure do i have to do $em->flush(); right after remove() or not. If i do, then of course it works, but then my script execution time goes too high.

Answer (score 3):

Methods `remove()` or `add()` does not perform any operation on database - `flush()` does. So you will still get the same results of `findOneBy` as before `remove()` - you have to call `flush()` to perform `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` on DB

Answer (score 0):

Flush should commit the changes to the database.
The entitymanager should however be aware of the changes that have not been flushed yet.

You can have a virtual dataset from your entitymanager while not flushing.

UPDATE From Doctrine documentation:
Just like persist, invoking remove on an entity does NOT cause an immediate SQL DELETE to be issued on the database. The entity will be deleted on the next invocation of EntityManager#flush() that involves that entity. This means that entities scheduled for removal can still be queried for and appear in query and collection results.

After an entity has been removed its in-memory state is the same as before the removal, except for generated identifiers.